# Python while enters an infinite loop when reading lines

Tags: python, while-loop, readline

I want to read the DS18B20 sensor data with the code below:

```py
filepath = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/w1_master_slaves"

with open(filepath) as fp:
    sensor=fp.readline()
    while sensor:
        print("Sensor: {}".format(sensor.strip()))
        with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + sensor.strip() + "/w1_slave") as fp1:
            sensor_data = fp1.read()
            print(sensor_data.strip())
    sensor=fp.readline()
```

The problem is that the while loop never steps to the next line, keeps looping at the first one.

What am I missing here?

PS. I'm totaly new with python, this is my very first python code

Comment: Because, `sensor` is never updated within loop. It keeps looping through first read value. Maybe indent the last line?

Comment: Is `sensor=fp.readline()` supposed to be in the loop? It's outside as posted here.

Comment: so, the `sensor=fp.readline()` should be indented one more time?

Comment: yes, and it works now! Thank you

Comment: @Austin, post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: Nevermind, you've got an answer; accept it. :)

Comment: It does for me, this is the only way I can reward your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem is `sensor` is never getting updated within loop. It keeps looping through first read value. This can be corrected by indenting the last line of your code.

I suggest using a `for` loop. When we simply iterate over file handler, we iterate over lines in file.

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for sensor in fp:
        print("Sensor: {}".format(sensor.strip()))
        with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + sensor.strip() + "/w1_slave") as fp1:
            sensor_data = fp1.read()
            print(sensor_data.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

**That because sensor isn't changed within the loop, try this**

```
filepath = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/w1_master_slaves"

with open(filepath) as fp:
    sensor = fp.readline()
        while (sensor):
            print("Sensor: {}".format(sensor.strip()))
            with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + sensor.strip() + "/w1_slave") as fp1:
                sensor_data = fp1.read()
                print(sensor_data.strip())
            sensor=fp.readline()
```